# How to click a button without any unique class attribute

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have troubles with clicking on a button that has a long, generated class that is not unique using xpath selectors. It has 2 nested elements - svg and span. I'm not sure if I should look for this button using them or maybe looking by class and choosing e.g. 2nd option.

I've tried the following selectors:

```
xpath = "//button[contains(@class, 'styled_ShareButton')](1)"
```

```
xpath = "//button span[contains('Add to favorites')]"
```

```
xpath = "//button[contains(@span, 'fa-heart')]"
```

```
xpath = "//svg[contains(@class, 'fa-heart')]"
```

But none of them worked.

Here's the button that I'm interested in (this is 2nd of 2 buttons with the same class)

```
<button class="styled__ShareButton-sc-1jdjzg3-3 feqRzW Button-sc-1emfup8-0 kFlIhg">
<svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="far" data-icon="heart" class="svg-inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16 " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
<span>Add to favourites</span>
</button>
```

Can someone tell me how to click on it or maybe point out a mistake I did in previous selectors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below XPaths :

```
xPath = "//span[contains(text(), 'Add to favourites')]//parent::button"
```

Or

```
xPath = "(//*[@id='react-app-root']//button[contains(@class, 'styled__ShareButton')])[last()]"
```

Or

```
xPath = "//*[@id='react-app-root']//span[contains(text(), 'Add to favourites')]//parent::button"
```

Or

```
xPath = "(//*[@id='react-app-root']//button[contains(@class, 'styled__ShareButton')])[2]"
```

Or

```
xPath = "(//button[contains(@class, 'styled__ShareButton')])[2]"
```

Or

```
xPath = "(//button[contains(@class, 'styled__ShareButton')])[last()]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The default xpath suggested by browser worked:

```
xpath = "//*[@id=\'react-app-root\']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]"
```

but if someone has better looking solution I would still appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect use case for a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

The attribute can be used to uniquely identify the button in the test, and will be more resilient to changes in your UI structure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'd argue it does provide an answer to the question. An alternative to absolute XPath, which will be brittle to changes in the UI, is to explicitly add an attribute to the component by which it can be located.

Comment: "I'm not sure if I should look for this button using them or maybe looking by class and choosing e.g. 2nd option"  -  the answer proposes a solution for how to look for the button in a way that decouples the test from the shape of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class^='styled__ShareButton-sc-'] span"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class]//span[text()='Add to favourites']"))).click();
  ```